# How to populate a fragment drawer list when clicking backbutton in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a Android function that allows user to click "back button" within the one of the fragments so that fragment drawer list can be displayed. Although this function(populating list view) is already realized by clicking a homeup button but users can sometimes click just a back button and want to make sure that the fragment drawer will be displayed.

The structure of the code is as follow.
I have a main activity class that extends ActionbarActivity and implements NavigationDrawerFragment class.

NavigationDrawerFragment has a function that opens or closes the drawer. Here I don't know how to access to the drawer functions in "NavigationDrawerFragment class".

My objective is, in the main activity,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    drawershow();

}
```

Here is my MainActivity class and NavigationDrawerFragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private CharSequence mTitle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity2);


        final String intent_message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
        if (intent_message!= null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), intent_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

        mTitle = getTitle();
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragmentToLaunch = getFragmentToLaunch(position);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragmentToLaunch)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {

            case CASE_SECTION_VIDEO_CALL:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_build_info) {
            String versionInfo = "SDK Version: " + sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
                    + "\n" + "Sample application version: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            Log.d(TAG, versionInfo);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    public Fragment getFragmentToLaunch(int position) {
        Fragment fragmentToLaunch = null;
        switch (position) {

            case CASE_FRAGMENT_VIDEO_CALL:
                fragmentToLaunch = new VideoCallFragment();
                break;
       }

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragmentToLaunch.setArguments(args);

        return fragmentToLaunch;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       here!
    }
}
```

The below is for NavigationDrawerFragment class.

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);



        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
               // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_sungpah,


                android.R.id.text1,


                new String[]{
                    ....

                }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                 /* host Activity */
                getActivity(),
                /* DrawerLayout object */
                mDrawerLayout,
                /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                 /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                 /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }
                // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }
                // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        if (!mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        //0,1,2,3
        //1 => my class.(video call)
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position; //<-- save as an integer.
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your Question?  How to access methods in a fragment from the Activity?

Comment: On a separate note, are you sure your DrawerLayout should be in the Fragment. Normal practice is to place it as the root component of an Activity. Same thing with the ActionBarDrawerToggle. Normally in the Activity.

Comment: Hi Kuffs! This is the sample code that the service I'm now using ( webRTC based video chat application ) and I'm now trying to modify it. Mostly it remains itself. The structure they make is ( I think ) they have a main activity that is shared by multiple fragments(video chat fragment, audio chat fragment etc). It makes a drawer class separate ( NavigationDrawerFragment.class). What I want to do is to show a list view ( it appears from hidden to left side of the screen - moving from left to right ) when "back button" clicked!

Comment: Sounds like a poor sample as this sounds a really bad way to implement a drawer. Also your idea of using the back button to make it show is rather weird. People expect their back button to go back.